# apache-poi WordToHtmlConverter not converting images properly

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using apache.poi to transform a word file into html. My document has text and images - the text can be converted to html just fine, but images are not converted. Is there any way to convert images as well?

```
HWPFDocumentCore wordDocument = WordToHtmlUtils.loadDoc(new FileInputStream("my_document_path"));

WordToHtmlConverter wordToHtmlConverter = new WordToHtmlConverter(DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument());
wordToHtmlConverter.processDocument(wordDocument);

org.w3c.dom.Document htmlDocument = wordToHtmlConverter.getDocument();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(htmlDocument);
StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);

TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer serializer = tf.newTransformer();
serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.MEDIA_TYPE,"text/image" );
serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
serializer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
out.close();

String result = new String(out.toByteArray());
File filename = new File("stored_html_path");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename); //the true will append the new data
fw.write(result);//appends the string to the file
fw.close();
```

Comment: Done proper code formatting.

Comment: Where is class WordToHtmlConvert from? I don't think this is provided as part of POI, right?

Comment: @centic WordToHTMlConverter provide from org.apache.poi.hwpf.converter

Comment: Oh, didn't know that POI had that class...

Comment: What kind of images do you have in your input files? IIRC that converter just silently discards stuff it does not know how to handle (WMFs, EMFs, OfficeDrawings, probably others).

Comment: I my input files as jpg and png images